# Query a row based on a Cell value returns nothing using PHP in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this:

```
$con1 = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','database');
$var = mysqli_query($con1,"select * from myTable where ID=2");
            $o = mysqli_fetch_array($var);
$u = $o['Username'];
$r = mysqli_query($con1,"select Value from myOtherTable where UserName='.$u.' and     Attribute='Male'");
echo $m['Value'];
```

The *echo $m['Value'];* does not return any value nor any error. When i run the query in command prompt:

```
select Value from myOtherTable where UserName='abcd' and Attribute='Male';
```

...it runs fine and also up in the php file when i hard code the 'UserName' value it works fine but when i try to use a variable, despite the row contains that very letters—which the variable contains, no output is given, when i run:

```
while ( $ko = $r->fetch_assoc() ) {
            printf( $ko['Value']);
        }
```

Please help. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
"SELECT Value FROM myOtherTable WHERE UserName='".$u."' AND Attribute='Male'"
```

Answer (score 0):

**The reason you are not getting any result** Because you did not fetch your second query
**Try this**

```
$con1 = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','database');
    $var = mysqli_query($con1,"select * from myTable where ID=2");
                $o = mysqli_fetch_array($var);
    $u = $o['Username'];
    $r = mysqli_query($con1,"select Value from myOtherTable where UserName='.$u.' and     Attribute='Male'");
     $m= mysqli_fetch_array($r);//**Add this line**
    echo $m['Value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you want fetch the value form an array.

```
 $con1 = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','database');
    $var = mysqli_query($con1,"select * from myTable where ID=2");
    $o = mysqli_fetch_array($var);
    foreach($o as $row){
        $u = $row['Username'];
    }
    $r = mysqli_query($con1,"select Value from myOtherTable where UserName='".$u."' and     Attribute='Male'");
    echo $m['Value'];
```